# How to write the XPath using sibling?

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to write the `XPath` using `sibling`?

I am trying to get the **price value** of the delivery fee using the `sibling`. But I am unable to get the `XPath` for the price tag below is the HTML code.

```
<div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
   <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-detail-capgrey"> Delivery Fee:</label>
</div>
<div class="grid_1 d-grid_2"> 
   <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-price text-align-right"> $9.00</label>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="grid_3 d-grid_10">
 <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-detail-capgrey"> Delivery Fee:</label>
  </div>
<div class="grid_1 d-grid_2">
 <label class="m-confirmation-modal-print-price text-align-right"> $9.00</label>
   </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//div[contains(., ' Delivery Fee:')]/following-sibling::div/label
```

**Explanation to xPath:** `//div[contains(., ' Delivery Fee:')]` finds a div on the top, then `/following-sibling::div` will select all next siblings `div` below our `div`. In our case only the next `div`. And finaly `/label` locates the element with value `$9.00`.

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
//label[contains(text(),' Delivery Fee:')]/parent:div/following-sibling::div/label
```

But yes `@Andrei` solution make much sense to use.